# Wordpress behind nginx reverse proxy doesnt work in https

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to run wordpress on a docker based cloud. The setup is:

[image: Wordpress Cloud Setup]

There is a server running a mysql array, which serves a container with Wordpress Running on Nginx. The setup is copied from [this dockerfile](https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx). The goal of this setup is to achieve a high throughput and be compatible with our cloud setup.

The wordpress container has a local ip, in the same subnet as the mysql array and Nginx reverse proxy, and a public port to run http (not https).

The reverse proxy is configured to run SSL for the wordpress container. Navigation works on both http and https, but when I try to log in the dashboard with HTTPS, I get this error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

The only meaningful error I found happens when I log in on the dashboard, on HTTP:

> [04-Nov-2014 23:16:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO in /usr/share/nginx/www/wp-config.php on line 86

but the dashboard works correctly on http.

In Wordpress configuration file I had to add the line:

> /* SSL Proxy */
>
> if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

**And I think this is the culprit.** I found this tip in the [official wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL),  and without it HTTPS doesnt load the CSS, either logged or not logged. I think maybe I should modify this line to suit my configuration?

Either this, or the nginx reverse proxy [configuration file](http://pastebin.com/ZmdTmC8J), I have no idea.

The nginx configuration file in the wordpress + nginx container is quite standard, and it's copied from [here](https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx/blob/master/nginx-site.conf).

Please help me :D

Comment: It seems your nginx proxy doesnt send the correct headers (or the nginx inside the WP container doesnt forward that header into PHP... ) Try debugging the output of the NGINX reverse proxy and then looking into what comes into the WP container

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: replace the various backends to a simple PHP script which dumps the headers (```$_SERVER``` i.e.) and see what happens... It might be that one of you nginx-servers just messes up the headers?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the Nginx server configuration `fastcgi_params`?

Comment: where do I find them? I guess it was the default ones

Comment: @Mascarpone Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: same problem here ... @Mascarpone did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 8):

I had some problem, I resolved in this way:

in my wp-config.php,

I added these lines:

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
      $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

BEFORE everything in the code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: if the line was put at the bottom of the config file, there will be a problem.  this is what fixed the problem for me.

Comment: was struggling with this for hours, until putting it before everything in the code, that did the trick! thanks!

Comment: yes, the placement of the snippet was crucial! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this block of code in wp-config.php for nginx reverse proxy => Apache

```
// When behind reverse proxy
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']= 'on';
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).