# Get Wordpress+Apache to work behind nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I'm trying to setup the following:

- docker container with nginx on localhost as a reverse-proxy for Wordpress, listening on localhost:80. It is also used as a reverse-proxy for other microservices.
- docker-compose container(s) with Wordpress+Apache, listening on localhost:4261. The docker-compose.yaml was taken from the [official example](https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/). The 'ports' directive was changed from "8000:80" --> "4261:80".

I tried following numerous guides and troubleshooters, but nginx keeps responding with "111 connection refused". Similar questions (which did not work for me): [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/642124/wordpress-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-doesnt-work-in-https) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite).

Any ideas?

nginx config:

```
server {
    # Listen HTTPS
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name ${NGINX_URL};
    ssl_certificate /certs/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /certs/private.key;
    
    location /wp/ {
        rewrite ^/wp/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4261/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    ...
}
```

wp-config.php:

```php
...
// If we're behind a proxy server and using HTTPS, we need to alert WordPress of that fact
// see also https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx is trying to connect to localhost **inside** the container. You have to either use host networking for the container or you need to [link the nginx container](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#external_links) to the WordPress container.

In the docker-compose file that would be:

```
external_links:
  - wordpress:wordpress
```

Then you can use

```
proxy_pass http://wordpress/
```

in your nginx config. You don't need to expose any port in the WordPress container.

Comment: Did not solve my problem, but did point me in the right direction (placing both projects on the same network). Thanks!